# Full text is not showing in alert dialog in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to show `alert dialog` to user on clicking on a `button`. I am trying like below

```
onPressButton() {
  Alert.alert(strings.tour_end);
}
```

**strings.tour_end** is "Great! Hope you like our product tour! Enjoy this app. We have some excited offers for you!"

This is how it is showing in `alert`. Is this bug in `react-native` ?[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have passed full message as Alert title, as per Alert API.

```
alert(title, message?, buttons?, options?, type?)
```

like below

```
alert("Great..!", strings.tour_end);
```

So title should be small message and you can show full message in message parameter.

if you want to develop customise Alert then use Modal API. [Check it](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html).

Or

You can use some third party npm modules to show customise alerts. which is also based on modal api.

```
npm install react-native-modalbox@latest --save
```

try this.

Answer (score 4):

**If you pass only text it will consider as a Title**

As per the documentation  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert..
you can pass values like this.

```
Alert.alert(
'Alert Title',
'My Alert Msg',
[
{text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed')},
{text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'), style: 'cancel'},
{text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
], 
{ cancelable: false }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you pass only a single text inside the 'alert' ,
for eg) `Alert.alert("hello")` , this will be considered as the Alert Title.**

The Alert title is supposed to be short so it won't display a large text.

So the first field in the 'alert()' is the 'Alert Title' and the next field is the 'Alert Message'.

Do like this :

```
Alert.alert('Alert Title', 'Alert Message', [
  {
    text: 'Cancel',
    onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
    style: 'cancel',
  },
  {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed')},
]);
```